# Command Prompt animation in html

Tags: html, command-prompt

I need to be able to create a animation something that would say something like "mastered command prompt" in a command prompt window in html is this possible? I want to add this to my html server based web resume witch is just my website with a couple of links and videos and my resume on a page. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand the question correctly you want a command prompt on your page? or an animation if it?

if you want a cmd prompt on your page you have to observe an html input element and bind it to an ajax communication which is able to make a "question-answer" communcation with your webservice..

OR

if you want only an animation.. you can append chars to an div with jquery or whatever with a 500ms delay or something like this..

OR

just make a .gif of it and bind it via

answered? ;)